# How do you create and access array elements in settings bundle

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios

I want to save strings as array elements in a Settings.bundle Root.plist and be able to access those strings from the Setting bundle on subsequent launches of my app. I could not find a good example of this anywhere. In xcode, I have created the Root.plist and it looks something like:

```
Key
iPhone Setting Schema
    Strings Filename
    Preference Items
        Item 0 (Title- My Title)
            Type           Title
            Title          My Title
            Identifier     My Identifier
            Values
                Item 0     my string 1
                Item 1     my string 2
                Item 3     my string 3
```

This produces xml as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>StringsTable</key>
<string>Root</string>
<key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Type</key>
        <string>PSTitleValueSpecifier</string>
        <key>Title</key>
        <string>My Title</string>
        <key>Key</key>
        <string>My Identifier</string>
        <key>Values</key>
        <array>
            <string>my string 1</string>
            <string>my string 2</string>
            <string>my string 3</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
```

I am using the following code to attempt an access of the Values from the Identifier key "My Identifier":

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *mystrings = [defaults arrayForKey:@"My Identifier"];
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [mystrings objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

The value of mystrings is 0 at runtime. Consequently, the Values of "my string 1", "my string 2", and "my string 3" are not getting printed by the NSLog.

Can someone help me with this. Also, what would be the correct way to update those values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part of your problem is mentioned under the heading ["Specifying Default Values for Preferences"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW24):

> default preference values from the application’s Settings bundle are not set until the Settings application runs. This means that if the user runs your application before running Settings, the default values specified in your Settings bundle are unavailable.

All the stuff in the Settings bundle doesn't get loaded for your app's defaults database until *after* the user opens the Settings Application. Does this seem stupid to you? Seems stupid to me. The result is that you need to register all those defaults initially yourself. I wrote this while I was trying to figure out what was going on; improvements can definitely be made, but it should get you started:

```
NSURL * settingsURL =  [[NSBundle bundleWithURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Settings" withExtension:@"bundle"]]
                         URLForResource:@"Root" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSDictionary * settingsDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:settingsURL];
NSArray * settingsArr = [settingsDict objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
for( NSDictionary * setting in settingsArr ){
    NSString * key = [setting objectForKey:@"Key"];
    if( !key ) continue;    // Some objects don't have keys
    if( ![defaults objectForKey:key] ){
        [defaults setObject:[setting objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"] 
                     forKey:key];
    }
}
```

Another problem that you have is that you don't get an array for `PSTitleValueSpecifier` keys when you do `[defaults objectForKey:@"myTitlePreferencesKey"]`; you just get one string. A `@"DefaultValue"` key/value pair is also required to be part of [that item's dictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSTitleValueSpecifier.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007015-SW1). Initially you will get that value, which must be a string. If you change the value, you'll get the string from the `Titles` array which has the same index as that object in the `Values` array. I'm pretty sure that if you have a `Values` array, you also have to have a `Titles` array.

For the second part of your question, if you want to change the values of any of the preferences, you simply do

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myValue 
                                          forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately that doesn't seem to work. The value of mystrings is still 0x0. Plus, I don't think this suggestion would work if you had multiple preference items since the key "Values" would not be unique. According to how I have interpreted the documentation I have read so far, the key "My Identifier" should be the one that I am supposed to specify as a unique key for your data. You may be on the right track, but as I said, it did not work.

Comment: @Jeff: The key _has_ to be unique; it's a dictionary. You can use whatever you want as the key, @"My Identifier", @"Value", @"Yellow Zebras", but only one of each key can exist. Can you clarify this file's location? I think that might be your real problem. What docs are you referring to?

Comment: Root.plist is part of the Settings.bundle which is within my Resources folder. Yes, I understand that I need to specify a unique key. When I create Preference items within the Root.plist file under xcode where the new item is a "Title" item, xcode automatically creates 4 keys (Type, Title, Identifier, and Default Value). You can change the "Default Value" key to be a "Values" key. When you do that, it creates an Item key (and you can keep adding more items). For the Item key, you can specify string values (e.g. "my string 1"). I will continue on the next comment (limited size).

Comment: So, when I said that Values would not be unique, I mean that the Values key that is generated by xcode would not be unique if I keep adding new Preference items. As for documentation, I have interpreted this from multiple searches on this subject. For example: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/Preferences/Preferences.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW11 step number 3 says "Change the value of the Identifier key to play_sounds_preference.".

Comment: Then the example code at Accessing Your Preferences in this documentation shows using the play_sounds_preference key

Comment: @Jeff: I definitely misunderstood the Settings.bundle business; it's rather different than what happens on Mac OS. Take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: @Josh: Ok thanks for helping me. What you are saying makes sense and I overlooked that the Default Value is required. However, I am not quite certain I understand the purpose of the Default Value. In my example, does the Default Value represent a default for the first item in my array (e.g. "my string 1"), or is the Default Value related to the Preference Key (in my case "My Identifier"). Based on the documentation you pointed to, it sounds like the later. If so, I don't understand what default value I should be assigning to "Default Value". Could you help clarify this?

Comment: @Jeff: You can assign any string you want as the "Default Value". It can, but doesn't have to, be the same as one of the values that are in either the "Values" array or the "Titles" array. I believe its purpose is, if you opened the Settings Application without having previously set a value (either in code or through the Settings App) for a particular key, its "Default Value" would be the one used. It probably makes the most sense for the "Default Value" string to be identical to one of the "Titles" strings.